# How should I try 3 times if my code failed to connect a web service in C#?

Tags: c#, web-services, robustness

Here is my code:

```
FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(Constant.IP);
reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);
reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
```

I would like to try to connect to the web service if my code fails to connect. Only after 3 times, I would like to give up.

How should I try?

I am thinking about `try catch` and count the failure time but I think there will be better solutions.

Comment: What type of webserives are they ?? A sharepoint or ??

Comment: That's FTP, not a web service. Also, don't retry unless you know _why_ you failed to connect.

Comment: Ohh yes, Sorry about it. It is ftp. 
My boss told me to try 3 times if it's fail. 
So I have to try.

Comment: Is there any way I can try for both ftp and web service?

Comment: Your boss telling you so doesn't sound like a good basis for technical decisions. What if the error is due to faulty credentials? You shouldn't retry three times then - the user would probably want that information as quickly as possible. And even if your credentials are hard-coded, retrying will most likely not remedy the situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
int faultCounter = 0;
bool faulted;
do {
  faulted = false;
  try {
    // perform service operation
  } catch {
    faultCounter++;
    faulted = true;
  }
} while (faulted && faultCounter < 3);
```

Comment: Thats a sample implementation, you still can add code for the `DontRetryMeException`.

Comment: Such an exception does not exist and there's no indication given as to which exceptions should dodge an attempt to retry. The opener gave no such requirement, so I was answering the question. You're right that I didn't attempt to out-smart the question, but on purpose. Others have noted this point already.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate your code in loop, and return or break if there is no exception.